# Google Login Session in Php

Tags: php, session, authentication, gmail, google-oauth

I programmed a Google Login for my website. The user needs to use his or her specific school gmail. However, I run into a problem. If the user accidentally tries to login with another gmail that isn't his school email, the website warns him "You should be using your school gmail" and brings him back to the login page. However, if he tries to click "Login with Google" again (because ideally he would pick the correct Google email address), the session for his previous Google account is still running and doesn't even give him an option to try his other gmail account. I don't know exactly what to do...do I destroy the session? Does the user have to manually log out? Here is the error handling code.

```
    unset($_SESSION['token']);
    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
    echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
        window.alert('You need to login with your school Google account.')
        window.location.href='http://websitename.com/login';
        </SCRIPT>");
```

Comment: Why not completely destroy the session and restart?  http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php

Comment: Yea, if you want to completely force a logout, just call `session_destroy()`. However, just know that it will also lose any/all additional information stored there. But at the point of login there shouldn't be much saved anyways.

Comment: Are you using `session_start()` before `unset($_SESSION['token']);` and also before using session variables everywhere else ? `session_start()` is needed even if you are trying to kill a session.

Comment: I am using session_start(). When I put in session_destroy() it goes to the logout page. I am not sure if I am explaining my problem well. I just know session_destroy() isn't doing quite what I need.

Comment: hello, I'm having the same problem, did u find a solution? @programmingperson

Answer (score 0):

If after destroying your session google authentication URL redirects you directly to your redirect file, it is probably because no new google access token has to be assigned. **In case you don't need to store and re-use the same access token and want the user to log in every time authenticating with Google, you have to revoke the token after using it.**

In order to revoke an access token, you have to execute the following line

```
$client->revokeToken();
```

Example code for this behavior would be:

```
$client->setAccessToken($access_token);

  if (!$client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    try {

      $plus = new Google_Service_Plus($client); // starts google profile (plus) service
      $me = $plus->people->get('me'); // saves account info
      $email = $me->emails[0]->value; // email
      $id = $me->id; // id
      $name = $me->name->givenName; // name
      $surname = $me->name->familyName; // surname

      $client->revokeToken();

      $user = updateUser($email, $name, $surname, $id, $pic, $shortener); // proprietary function

    } catch (Google_Exception $e) {

      abortLogin("couldn't check google profile details", true); // proprietary function

    }

  } else {

     abortLogin("invalid token", true); // proprietary function

  }

session_destroy();
```